# Jquery function when a textbox loses focus

Tags: jquery

I have textbox that I want to run some jquery when the textbox loses focus, so after the user clicks out of the text box.

I have tried to do this

```
$("#textbox").focusout(function () {
    alert("hello");

});
```

but I get an error saying Object doesn't support this property or method.

How can I do this then?

Comment: You've said in comments it's 1.4.2, are you *absolutely* sure? Is it possible you're including an older version of jQuery, possibly further down in the page?

Comment: Have you imported jQuery into the page?

Comment: yes i am sure I only import it once on the master page and no where else I don't have have an earlier version on my system. yes jQuery is imported to the page. other functions such as button() are being used and working just fine.

Comment: @twal - Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: So you just gave up and used `blur`? *sigh*

Comment: Ha Ha no, when i re-downloaded 1.4.2 and replaced it with the new on focusout worked for me. Not sure why but it works now so I am happy!

Comment: make sure you have enclosed jquery in  @section scripts { }

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`focusout`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) was added in v1.4. Three thoughts:

1. Could you be using an earlier version of jQuery?
2. Does your field really have the id `textbox`?
3. Are you also using Prototype or MooTools (or anything else that might be taking over `$`)? If so, use jQuery's [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode and use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Other than that, it should (does) work.

Here's an example (using an alert as you did): http://jsfiddle.net/QzmZp/1/

and another not using an alert (because that freaked IE7 out): http://jsfiddle.net/QzmZp/2/

Someone earlier asked about browser versions, I've tried the above with Chrome 5, IE6, IE7, and FF3.6; all fine.

I did both an `input` and a `textarea` because I wasn't sure which you were using.

Comment: i just double checked. it is 1.4.2

Comment: double checked again my field has an id of textbox i copied and pasted it to the selector just to be sure. and still the same.
Is it does it both on IE and FF browser doesn't effect it.

Comment: @twal - Do you have another library on the page, prototype for example?

Comment: nope I don't have any other libary. I just re-down loaded jquery 1.4.2 and replaced the existing with the new and and voila focusout worked. Weird.. whatever, Thank you guys for all your help!!!

Comment: @twal: With respect, why accept an answer related to `blur` then? It seems to me neither answer solved your problem (though both tried to). Accepting an answer is for when the answer *solved* the problem; *upvoting* is for answers that helped, even if they didn't solve the problem. Neither of these did the former, though both did the latter.

Comment: really? does it matter that much? There were only two answers. Blur did solve my problem which was to get the textbox to show up when the user clicked out of the text box. So I clicked it as the answer to mainly mark that my problem was solved.

Comment: I do appreciate your help though please don't get me wrong. Thank you

Comment: @Twal: Glad that helped. But I didn't mean you should accept *this* answer, it didn't actually solve the problem any more than the other one! :-) If you feel you need to accept one or the other, please do go with your original choice. And no, it doesn't matter that much, but the idea is that questions with *accepted* answers have actually been answered. What I'd say you should do is post your own answer saying exactly what you said (re-downloaded and it worked), then accept that (there'll be a two-day delay before you can do that).

Comment: @twai what T. J. said :) If neither answer is the solution, simply upvote if they helped. What you can do is post your *own* solution as an answer and then accept that (when you are able to - usually in 2 days).

Comment: gotcha, thanks guys. This is a good site. lots of people willing to help I like it

Answer (score 19):

```
jQuery("#textbox").blur(function() {
  alert("hello");
});
```

`blur` is the event that fires when an element loses focus. Check out [`jQuery.blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

**EDIT**

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you are really trying to use `focusout` check out [T. J. Crowder's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151330/jquery-function-when-a-textbox-looses-focus/3151371#3151371). For your situation though, the `blur` event might be want you need since you want to detect the loss-of-focus on the textbox itself. `focusout` fires when an element or any element *inside* that element loses focus.

Comment: blur worked for me thank you! Not sure why i get the error on focus out but this will work.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: `focusout` fires for the textbox as well, it *also* bubbles though.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#idOfTextField").blur(function(){

  //your code

});
```

Comment: Try to provide improved answer. If you are answering same as already done

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        ////////////////////////ALL textbox to upper
        $("input[type=text]").blur(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
        });
    });
```

To convert all textbox to upper when they lose focus.