# iOS detect when a textarea loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios

How can I detect when a textarea loses focus on an iOS unit?

My problem:
When a user taps the textarea I want to resize certain elements on the page - to make up for the keyboard the flaps up. When the textarea then loses focus, I want to resize the elements back into place.

I currently use `onfocus` and `onblur` but `onblur` does not seem to work if a user starts to scroll while the keyboard is still up.

My current code:

```
document.getElementById("myTextarea").onfocus=function(e) {
    // resize elements, keyboard has focus
};
document.getElementById("myTextarea").onblur=function(e) {
    // resize elements back to default, keyboard lost focus
};
```

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: maybe you could do something with the `onscroll` event. I've got no specific ideas, but it might just help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151330/jquery-function-when-a-textbox-loses-focus

Comment: @twodayslate sorry forgot to mention I need something that does not require jQuery :/

Comment: @Alosyius No need for jQuery. [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) is a standard event. Anyway, you should be using `document.getElementById("myTextarea").addEventListener("focusout", function() { /* Code */ });` rather than attributes